# Issue with oAuth in docusign in django python

Tags: django, python-3.x, docusignapi

The issue is while requesting for token, we are getting the "Invalid Grant" error (Response - 400).
Please find attached the python code which we are using for the same.

We also tried same with postman and getting the same error message.

We also added callback url on docusign panel

Please see below the code :-

```
import json
import requests
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
import base64
from .utils import return_csv_values, np, get_current_day_month, return_csv_values_application

from .process_docments import embedded_signing_ceremony_contract, embedded_signing_ceremony_application
import pandas as pd

from .models import DocumentSigned

CLIENT_AUTH_ID = 'my integration id'
CLIENT_SECRET_ID = 'my secret id'


# Create your views here.
def get_access_token(request):
    base_url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth"
    auth_url = "{0}?response_type=code&scope=signature click.manage organization_read permission_read dtr.documents.read&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}" \
        .format(base_url, CLIENT_AUTH_ID, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth_login")
    # print(request.build_absolute_uri())
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)

#callback url
def auth_login(request):
    access_code = request.GET['code']
    # return HttpResponse(access_code)

    base_url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"
    auth_code_string = '{0}:{1}'.format(CLIENT_AUTH_ID, CLIENT_SECRET_ID)
    print(auth_code_string)
    auth_token = base64.b64encode(auth_code_string.encode('utf-8'))
    auth_token = auth_token.decode("utf-8")
    print(auth_token)
    req_headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {0}".format(auth_token), "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    post_data = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': access_code}
    try:
        r = requests.post(base_url, data=post_data, headers=req_headers)
        print(r)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return HttpResponse(str(e))
```

Comment: you are using Auth Code Grant. How is your IK (Client ID) defined? is it defined for implicit grant? do you get the UI to login into DocuSign OK? do you get a code but then get the error trying to exchange it for a token?

Comment: Yes, IK is defined in "Authorization Code Grant" for User Application.
Yes, we are getting token from UI but error in token generation via Python script (auth code is generated in Python script).

Comment: can you try to create a new clientSecret?

Comment: we already tried it multiple times

Comment: in my code , I use ASCII encoding and not UTF-8. I also add the redirectUri with "redirect_uri". I'll post my code below

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I use, note a few differences from what you're doing:

```
        string endpoint = string.Format("{0}/oauth/token", accountServerUrl);
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        values.Add("code", token);
        if (redirectUri != null)
            values.Add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth);
        var encodedAuth = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", encodedAuth));
```